Can i link my old tv to my new monitor (daisy chain)?
I am looking to daisy chain my tv to my monitor, but do not have a dp slot in the old tv, just hdmi. My new monitor has 1 dp slot and 1 hdmi (hdmi currently in use).
I have tried every other fix that doesn't involve daisy chaining them, please help!

There's displayport to hdmi adaptors. Plug one into your PC's Displayport slot, and use a HDMI cable to connect that to your TV and it should be detected as another display.

As far as I know it requires 2 DP connections on the monitor and the monitor must support chaining.
One DP used as input (from the computer) and the other used as output to the other monitor/TV.
The outgoing DP can be converted to HDMI using a converter to get it on the TV, but not all monitors with chaining ability like that particular setup (and you won't find it in the manual usually) so that will be trail and error.
And your graphics card in the computer must also support this chaining on the DP output (most do, but not all, especially older cards may not support it).
Using a HDMI output on the GFX card, converting that to DP to go to the first monitor, will never work. (HDMI just doesn't support it.)
Only the last monitor in the chain can be HDMI (and it isn't guaranteed to work in that case as I already said above).
